# Connect to WebSocket From Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, force.com-sites, python

Below is my code -

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
<html>

    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cs8.salesforce.com/support/api/28.0/interaction.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var webSocket;
        var data = "";

        function openSocket()
        {
            // Open server socket
            if (webSocket !== undefined && webSocket.readyState !== WebSocket.CLOSED) {
                alert("WebSocket is already opened");
                return;
            }

            webSocket = new WebSocket('wss://13.65.193.191:8003/test');

            if (webSocket === undefined)
            {
                alert("Error creating socket...");
                return;
            }

            webSocket.onopen = function()
            {
                alert("in onopen callback");
            }

            webSocket.onmessage = function(event)
            {
                alert("in onmessage callback   " + data);
            }

            webSocket.onclose = function()
            {
                alert("in onclose callback");
            }
        }

        </script>   

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function WebSocketTest()
        {
            if ("WebSocket" in window)
            {
                alert("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");

                // Let us open a web socket

                var ws = new WebSocket('wss://13.65.193.191:8003/test');
                ws.onopen = function()
                {
                    // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
                    final_query = {query: 'hi',dialog: 'initial',intent: ''};
                    json_query = JSON.stringify(final_query);
                    ws.send(json_query);
                    alert("Message is sent... "+final_query);
                };

                ws.onmessage = function (evt) 
                { 
                    var received_msg = evt.data;
                    var json=JSON.parse(received_msg);
                    alert("Message is received... "+json);
                };

                ws.onclose = function()
                { 
                    // websocket is closed.
                    alert("Connection is closed..."); 
                };
            }

            else
            {
                // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
                alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="openSocket();">Open Socket</button>
        <div id="sse">
            <a href="javascript:WebSocketTest()">Run WebSocket</a>
        </div>
        <input placeholder="Your id" id='name' name="name" type="text" class="form-control" required="autofocus" />
    </body>
</html>
```

**I am getting the below exception -**

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://xx.xx.xxx.191:8003/test' failed: Error
>   in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED openSocket @
>   TestBot:23 onclick @ TestBot:91
>
> TestBot:58 WebSocket connection to 'ws://xx.xx.xxx.191:8003/test'
>   failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Does salesforce support websockets from vf pages?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use Websockets from a visualforce page.

Here is a nice example:
[Example Websockets from VF Page](http://www.johnbrunswick.com/2014/01/internet-of-customers-custom-visualforce-page-with-web-sockets-arduino-temperature/)

Comment: usually best practice on SFSE is to include relevant bits into your answer and not just link to another 3rd party site as that link could go dead

Comment: In Example they have use -  var socket = io.connect("http://192.168.1.100", {port: 3001})

i need to connect using WebSocket.

Comment: do you have any example where they have use WebSocket ?

Answer (score 0):

@Nirmallya Ghosh your doing correct, did you checked with socket that is created in   WSS OR WS , and is that Socket is running in forever mode.
check this using MQTT.Fx application to check whether your socket is running with same credeantials.

are able to solve this? if not try with **Paho client** libraries

https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/js/

you can connect a wedsocket from this.